# CSS when i set the width of an img element how do i make it so the other img elements will have different width?

Tags: html, css, image

I wanted to change the width of an image to make it scale so i used this code

```
img {
    width: 16%; 
    height: auto;
    }
```

The problem is the other images on the site have the same 16% width because they all use the same html `<img>` tag

How do i change it so the one image stays on 16% of its original width but others will have 100%?

Answer (score 2):

You should use CSS classes or IDs to change the appearance of separate images:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
img.portrait {    /* Note the .portrait designation: this is the same class name we defined in the HTML */
  width: 16%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x200" class="portrait" />  <!-- note the class of portrait -->
```

That being said, its not always possible to have access to the markup and it sounds like you are using the same `img` tag for all your images. If this is the case your only real option would be to use an attribute selector:

```css
img[src="http://placehold.it/200x100"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
img[src="http://placehold.it/100x200"] {
  width: 16%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x200" />
```

```
img[src="/imagename.png"]
```

That way you use the `img`'s `src` attribute to differentiate the images from one another.

Comment: I havent tried it out yet because the answer below worked but i will try it out thanks!

Comment: @JeremyBoard it is a CSS attribute selector: more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @ChrisSpittles oh ok, there's a bit of css I don't know yet :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set any image you want to style to have a class..

Html:

```
<img src="photo.jpg" class="myphoto" />
```

Css:

```
.myphoto{
width:16%;
}
```

Make different classes for different styles you want. :)

Comment: Yeah, css is a bit confusing at first. But once you get this classes thing down, it's a lot easier

Comment: Also how do i give u +rep? Do i have to have 15 reputation first?

Comment: Yeah, you have to have 15 I think... But that's OK :)

Comment: Ooh im sorry for that :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline styling when you have exceptions to the rule.
Example:

```
<img src="imgurl.com/img.jpeg" style="width:16%:" />
```

It is recommended you use CSS classes whenever possible though.